# How can I develop a popup that open on a button click (Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, popup

Any one can refer me a link or a demo of code for developing a popup using angularjs.

I have tried the following code but it's not working.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngMap', 'ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "views/home.php",
            controller: 'PopupDemoCont'
        })
        .when("/profile.php", {
            templateUrl: "views/profile.php"

        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        });
});

myApp.controller("ImageController", ["$scope", function($scope) {

    $scope.logoimage = "images/logo.png";
    $scope.bgtextimage = "images/bgtextimage.png";

}]);

myApp.controller("PopupDemoCont", ["$scope", "$modal", function($scope, $modal) {
    $scope.open = function() {
        console.log('opening pop up');
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'views/popup.php',
            controller: 'PopupCont'
        });
    };
}]);

myApp.controller("PopupCont", ["$scope", "$modalInstance", function($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.close = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

In bellow html, I set ng-controller but it isn't working.

```
<div class="book_div">
    <div class="book_content">
        <p id="book-text">Facing Immigration
            <br> Problems?
        </p>
        <p>Helpful Guid To Navigate Your Case</p>
        <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><img ng-src="{}" class="center-block img-responsive">
        </div>
        <a class="submit-button  book_btn" ng-click="open()">Free download</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is giving the Error:

> [$injector:unpr].

Comment: Actually you are on right track, make sure you are using latest angular ui bootstrap library and its been included in your HTML.. also 
kindly post full error message shown in browser console

Comment: check out https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal link. latest ui bootstrap modal has $uibModal

Answer (score 0):

You can use uibModalinstance.

On button click call the function open.

code for open function:

```
$scope.open = function(uuid,name){
var instance = $uibModal.open({
                        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                        templateUrl: 'common/common/partials/delete-
                                      confirm.tpl.html',
                        controller: function ($uibModalInstance, 
                                                $scope) {
                            $scope.name = Name;
                            $scope.icon = "fa-cogs";
                            $scope.description = "Yo have opened uib 
                              Popup" 
                            $scope.delete = function () {                                  
                          $uibModalInstance.close($scope.deleteValue);
                            };

                            $scope.cancel = function () {
                                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                            };
                        }
                    });
}
```

I have used this code for deleting my record. You can use in your way, if you want to take response of Popup you can use:

```
instance.result.then(function (option) {
// Your code here            
                    }, function () {
                        console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
                    });
```

HTML template will be like:

```
<div class="modal-header gray_background">
            <h4><b>Permanently Delete - <i class="fa {{icon}} folderIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{name}} </b></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <span data-ng-bind-html="description"></span>

            <center style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <div>Type "delete" to confirm
                    <input type="text" class="input" ng-model="deleteValue" required />
                </div>
            </center>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer gray_background">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" ng-click="delete()">Delete</button>
        </div>
```

Hope this would be helpful, if you have any further query you can ask.
Thanks!